# How do I find the event time difference between two non consecutive events in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I want to calculate the time difference between two non consecutive event in Apache Flink. An Event consists of a name and a timestamp. Ex:

E1("A", timestamp) -> E2("B", timestamp) -> E3("C", timestamp)

In this case I want to calculate the timestamp difference between E3 and E1. Any ideas on how to make it work in Flink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since E1 & E3 have different keys, you'd need to use a non-keyed window (`.windowAll()`), see [this doc](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/). Since you typically can't rely on the original order of events being preserved, in your custom ProcessWindowFunction you'd have to sort them by timestamp to be able to reliably calculate a delta.

Comment: Thank you. I will give a look at the linked docs